# Want to perform click event on previous and next button using mongodb id, it will definitly not work because mongodb Ids wont be sequential

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

Want to perform click event on previous and next button using mongo database id, it will definitely not work because  mongo database Ids wont be sequential. So is there any alternative?.

Comment: If your ids are (3,7,8,11,21) and you want to get back and forth from 8, you can still get the first one that is >8 or <8.

Comment: i am fetching id from mongo and those are in this format (601689f251b8e80a309ccf4b) I get id using params. when i click next button using logic +1. obviously this logic won't work at all.

Comment: Why not? The next one will still be the first one with `{_id : {$gt: ObjectId("601689f251b8e80a309ccf4b"}}`.